# How do you compile multiple kernels from the git repository?

Tags: kernel, 9.04, git

I've been trying to identify a kernel change that has killed hibernate on my Dell Inspiron 600m and I've made some good progress by checking out the kernel source from the git repository and rolling a kernel that does not have this bug (version 2.6.28-18.60). I'm now trying to compile the next kernel in the change log (version 2.6.28-19.61) but the build is failing with the error message:

```
  INSTALL fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko
strip:/home/spinlock/kernel/9.04/source/debian/linux-image-2.6.28-19-core3//lib/modules/2.6.28-19-core3/kernel/fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko: File format not recognized
make[4]: *** [fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-core3] Error 2
make: *** [binary-core3] Error 2
```

I've been using the instructions for rolling a kernel [here](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2009/09/08/how-to-compile-a-kernel-for-ubuntu-jaunty-revised/) and I can compile the first version but I get a failure when I try to switch to the next branch and compile from there. Is there a "make dep" or a "make clean" that I might be missing in the build process?

Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to save time between compiling the kernels but you do need to "make clean" and start from scratch each time.

Answer (score 3):

This error was caused by not running "make clean" before building the kernel packages. "make clean" and the problem goes away.